# Product measure spaces: Why is it that $A_{\omega_1} = \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty (A_n)_{\omega_1}$?

Tags: measure-theory, intuition, product-measure

I'm studying measure theory and I cannot wrap my head around this:

$A_{\omega_1} = \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty (A_n)_{\omega_1}$

The definition is
$A_{\omega_1} = \begin{cases}
A_2 & \omega_1 \in A_1 \\
\emptyset & otherwise
\end{cases}$ and we have $A = \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n$ and for any $A_n$ we have $A_n = A_{n,1} \times A_{n,2}$

So what I'm thinking is, $\exists n$ such that $\omega_1 \in  A_{n,1}$. Let all such $n$ form index set $I$ and therefore $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty (A_n)_{\omega_1} = \bigcup_{n\in I} (A_n)_{\omega_1} = \bigcup_{n\in I} A_{n,2}$

But if $I$ is not empty, then $A_{\omega_1} = \left(\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n\right)_{\omega_1} = \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_{n,2}$

So why $A_{\omega_1} = \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty (A_n)_{\omega_1}$ instead of
$A_{\omega_1} \supseteq \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty (A_n)_{\omega_1}$

?

EDIT: I think I figured it out.

My problem was assuming that if you had $A_n = B_n \times C_n$ then 
$$\bigcup_n A_n = \bigcup_n B_n \times \bigcup_n C_n$$ but actually
$$\bigcup_n A_n \subseteq \bigcup_n B_n \times \bigcup_n C_n$$

So in light of this, the definition $A_{\omega_1} = \begin{cases}
A_2 & \omega_1 \in A_1 \\
\emptyset & otherwise
\end{cases}$ does not make sense when applied like this $\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n\right)_{\omega_1}$, that is not well defined. So therefore $A_{\omega_1} = \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty (A_n)_{\omega_1}$ is just the definition. I think the book was just not clear about that.

Comment: I recommend that you clarify your definitions / notations, e.g. what does $(A_{n})_{\omega}$ mean?

Comment: @Julien There is no explicit definition in the book. I presumed it means: $(A_n)_{\omega_1} = \begin{cases}
A_{n,2} & \omega_1 \in A_{n,1} \\
\emptyset & otherwise
\end{cases}$